# Scrapy:: How to use "not" in CSS selector to skip elements

Tags: css-selectors, scrapy

Is there anyway to use such selector in scrapy?

I tried following but getting index out of range error

`response.css('.breadcrumbs > ul > li:not[class^="home"]').extract()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should enclose `not` expression in brackets like this

```
response.css('.breadcrumbs > ul > li:not([class^="home"])').extract()
```

Comment: Did you read the question? What exactly wrong in the answer in context of 'not' syntax in css selector? Is it wrong that `not` expression should be enclosed in the brackets? Or may be your "should-use" expression magically doesn't need it?

Comment: Sorry my bad. What I meant was that: when you use the `^=` you are saying "*begins with*", thus it may be better to use a `:not` with the `*=` that means "*contains*". So if you use what you have doesn't work, you can also try to use: `:not([class*="home"])`. (Which worked for me.)